# Programmatically change sorting order in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I'd like to give the user the possibility to change the sorting order (asc / desc) in a data structure. As far as I know, this is done changing the order of `$a` and `$b`in the code, but I'd like to programmatically change this to avoid redundant code.

I made a working example:

```perl
use 5.018;
use warnings;

# Supply any argument to change sorting order
my $sorting_direction = $ARGV[0];

my $data = {
          'item1' => {
                         'min'  => 4,
                         'size' => 825,
                         'max'  => 256,
                       },
          'item2' => {
                         'min'  => 4,
                         'size' => 130,
                         'max'  => 65,
                       },
        };


if (defined $sorting_direction) {
    foreach my $item (sort { $$data{$a}{'size'} <=> $$data{$b}{'size'} } keys %{$data} ) {
        say "$item\t", $$data{$item}{'size'};
    }
} else {
    foreach my $item (sort { $$data{$b}{'size'} <=> $$data{$a}{'size'} } keys %{$data} ) {
        say "$item\t", $$data{$item}{'size'};
    }   
}
```

Giving any parameter will change the `sorting_direction`. Can I do this without the *if* conditional?

Comment: I'm impressed by both Skeeve's answer (for it's simplicity and helpfulness in better understanding the sorting mechanism) and ikegami's answer (probably more elegant and also pointing to a nice module). If I could I would accept both!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A generic solution is to use different compare functions.

```
my %sorters = (
   by_size_asc  => sub { $data->{$a}{size} <=> $data->{$b}{size} },
   by_size_desc => sub { $data->{$b}{size} <=> $data->{$a}{size} },
   # ...
);

@ARGV
   or die("usage\n");

my $sorter = $sorters{$ARGV[0]}
   or die("Invalid sort function \"$ARGV[0]\".\n");

my @sorted_keys = sort $sorter keys(%$data);
```

You could also use different sort functions, such as when using the great [Sort::Key](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) module.

```
use Sort::Key qw( ikeysort rikeysort );

my %sorters = (
   by_size_asc  => sub { ikeysort  { $data->{$_}{size} } @_ },
   by_size_desc => sub { rikeysort { $data->{$_}{size} } @_ },
   # ...
);

@ARGV
   or die("usage\n");

my $sorter = $sorters{$ARGV[0]}
   or die("Invalid sort function \"$ARGV[0]\".\n");

my @sorted_keys = $sorter->( keys(%$data) );
```

Comment: `nsort_by` and `rev_nsort_by` from [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) could also be used similarly to those Sort::Key functions.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the first case because it solved also a second need: to have the possibility to choose between `<=>` and `cmp` if the value is not numeric.

Comment: @Grinnz, I suppose, but that module only offers a tiny subset of what Sort::Key does.

Answer (score 8):

As <=> has a value of -1, 0 or 1, you can multiply with -1 to get the opposite sorting order.

So if your $sorting_direction is 1 or  -1 use

```
$sorting_direction * ( $$data{$a}{'size'} <=> $$data{$b}{'size'} )
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's always going to be slower because it's a full extra operation, if performance is not as much a concern as code cleanliness you could just [reverse](https://perldoc.pl/functions/reverse) the list when the opposite sorting direction is chosen. Note that this would be slightly different in the case of sorting equal elements, as sort in Perl is normally stable (equal elements stay in the same order they originally were).

```
my @sorted = sort { $$data{$a}{'size'} <=> $$data{$b}{'size'} } keys %{$data};
@sorted = reverse @sorted if $reverse;
```